# What is the exclamation mark in Spree::Product.create(exclamation mark) method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I ran into some problems with Spree and saw [this code](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/spree-user/rJRM7RsVBG4/OerusRJpBAAJ), which mentions `Spree::Product.create!` (rather than `Spree::Product.create` without `!`)

I would like to understand the differences between the 2 methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bang versions (e.g. Spree::Product.create!) raise an exception if the record is invalid. The non-bang versions don’t: Spree::Product.create return false.

Ref: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. So the method is inherited from Active Record?